# try to create a search using flask and flask_sqlachemy

Tags: python, flask, search, flask-sqlalchemy

I try to create a flask search but when it does not show me any error, it always shows me no result 
this is my code in app.py

```
@app.route("/search", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def shearch():
    if request.form == 'POST':
        search = request.form.get("search")
        results = Books.query.filter_by(search=request.form.search).all
        return render_template('search.html', results=results, search=search)
    return render_template('search.html')
```

and in html file

```
<form class="search" action="/search" method="post">
    <fieldset class="search">
        {{ form.search.label }} {{ form.search(placeholder='search') }}
    </fieldset>

    <div class="submit-button">
        {{ form.submit }}
    </div>

    <table>
        {% if not results|length %}
        <h6> No results found. Please try again.</h6>
        {% else %}
        <tr>
            <th>isbn</th>
            <th>title</th>
            <th>author</th>
            <th>year</th>
        </tr>
        {% for result in results %}
        <tr>

            <th><a href="api/{{result['isbn']}}"> {{result['isbn']}}</th>

            <th><a href="books/{{result['title']}}"> {{result['title']}}</th>

            <th> {{result['author']}}</th>

            <th> {{result['year']}}</th>

        </tr>
        {% endfor %} {% endif %}


    </table>
```

it show me no result at all 
 i try another way in the app.py file

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        search = str(form.search.data)
        results = Books.query.filter((Books.title, Books.author, Books.year, Books.isbn).like(search=form.search.data)).all()
        return render_template('search.html', results=results, search=search, form=form)
```

Comment: first use `print()` to see what you get from database. Maybe it gives empty result.

Comment: BTW: shouldn't be `all()` with `()` in first version?

Comment: you should use `print()search)` to see what you get from `search = request.form.get("search")` . AND rather you should use this `search` instead of `request.form.search` in `filter_by(search=search)`

Comment: thank you for you help the print(search) show me none, when i tray to change it to   `results = Books.query.filter_by(search=search).all()` but it raised another error (sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Entity '<class '__main__.Books'>' has no property 'search')

Comment: maybe you should use column name which you have in database, not `search` - `filter_by(column_name=search)`. And you should check if your template generate `<input ... name="search">` which sends data avalable in code as `request.form.get("search")`

Comment: i try that but the main reason for this app is to search in the books database that containe ( title,author,year,isbn) .whene i use ` result = Books.query.all() ` it show me all the result , but i want to filter it by data that came from the search form

Comment: is ther a way to convert this ` "SELECT * FROM books WHERE title LIKE :search OR author LIKE :search OR isbn LIKE :search OR year LIKE :search",{'search':search}).fetchall() ` to a flask_sqlalchemy query ??

Comment: if you want to search by data from form then you have to use every column's name separatelly like `filter_by(title=search)`, `filter_by(author=search)`, etc. SQLAlchemy should have also functin to join it with `OR` and to use `LIKE` instead of `=`. It should have also method to execute directly SQL query. But I would have to use Google to get more details.

Comment: Using Google `"SQLAlchemy OR LIKE"` I found [SQLAlchemy query with OR/AND/like common filters](http://www.leeladharan.com/sqlalchemy-query-with-or-and-like-common-filters) - so `flask_sqlalchemy` should also use this methods (or very similar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i fix it Special thanks to furas and a firend of mine 
the code should be

```
    form = SearchForm()
    search = form.search.data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        search = form.search.data
    search = search.strip() 
    results = Books.query.filter(or_(Books.title.ilike(f'%{search}%'), Books.author.ilike(f'%{search}%'), Books.year.ilike(f'%{search}%'), Books.isbn.ilike(f'%{search}%'))).all()

     return render_template('search.html', results=results, form=form, search=search)
    return render_template('search.html', form=form, search=search)
```

that will fix it and search in the database